# Displaying standalone attribute table as a feature layer

Tags: layers, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, features

Using ArcGIS Pro, I have a feature class, which I converted the selected attributes into a standalone attribute table.

Having cleared my selection, I want to then know how to convert that table into a feature layer?

Comment: I Think you want [Make Table View](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-table-view.htm), you cant create a feature layer if you only have a table with no geometries

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! Make sure to take the [tour] to get familiar with what is expected of a high-quality, focused question. In general, always opt for more information than less. Can you be more specific about what the feature class was, and what process you used when you say "converted the selected attributes"? What is the desired outcome? It sounds like you're trying to get a subset of the initial layer, with the geometry, but with fewer of the attributes. Is that the case?

Comment: @JoshC I used the 'export' function on the attribute table to make a standalone attribute table from the selected attributes. The feature class represents bird species, with a geometry type of Polygon. What you mentioned is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: There's not much clarity here. As a rule, you need to be careful not to lose the linkage between the source table and the subset copy.  Standalone tables cannot render geometry which is not present, but if the primary key isn't lost, you can join it back to the source geometry (if it hasn't been altered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ArcGIS's built-in **Feature Class to Feature Class** tool, found in the **Conversion > To Geodatabase** toolbox. Though this tool is in the Geodatabase section, it can just as easily export to a shapefile, provided the *Output Location* specified is a folder rather than a geodatabase.

To create your subset, do one (or both) of the following:

1. Run the tool with an active selection.
2. Specify an expression to filter the features.

Note that doing both of the above will result in your output being filtered twice.

If desired, use the *Field Map* to remove, modify, or even add fields to the output. Note that I wouldn't actually *want* to sum the fields shown in the screenshot below, but know that it is possible to calculate derived attributes at the point of conversion, rather than doing it in a separate step later.

Click **Run**, and there you have it!

[image: feature class to feature class]

[image: subset output]